# AAPT compiler error in Android studio, what is the problem

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNI4w.png)

can't find the error

can anybody help me with this? I'm using kotlin in android studio

Answer (score 0):

try Andriod studio clean  project and rebuild otherwise invalid Caches & restart